# How can i use Google Recaptcha V3 without adding domains to admin console?

Tags: recaptcha, recaptcha-v3, react-google-recaptcha

I have a web-app that has no specific domain. (i mean specific domain after deployment. not local-host)
it doesn't have specific domain because we have more than 300 clients who want to add our code to their websites and the web-app runs on their website as a widget. (not an Iframe)
and we can not get 300 domains from our clients because we don't know them.
is there any way to use re-captcha on this project without introducing domains to admin console?